# Laravel Scout: only search in specific fields

Tags: laravel-scout

**Laravel Scout**: Is there a way that I search in only a specific field?

At the moment this line is working fine:

```
    $es = Element::search($q)->get();
```

But it searches **title**, **shortdescription** and **description** fields. I need it to only search in **title** field.

Answer (score 25):

You just need to change your `toSearchableArray` method from your model by adding the following code:

```
/**
 * Get the indexable data array for the model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $array = $this->only('title', 'description');

    $related = $this->user->only('name', 'email');

    // Customize array...

    return array_merge($array, $related);
}
```

Then call `php artisan scout:import "App\YourModel"` to reindex the new records.

Note:

- `$this->only('title', 'description')` will search only for its title and description fields
- `$this->user->only('name', 'email')` will also search for its name and email from a related Model

So you can retrieve the related data by adding `->load('user')` in your search method like the following code:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('q');

    return Task::search($query)->get()->load('user');
}
```

## UPDATE

If you're trying to retrieve the data using ->paginate() method, you must need to load the relations separately:

```
...
$tasks = Task::search($query)->paginate($request->get('per_page'));

$tasks->load('user');

return $tasks;
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The `array_merge()` will fail. The var `$related` is not an array by itself, needs to be like `$related->all()` to return an array.

Comment: The code was tested before publishing. Perhaps Laravel has updated it in new versions. I'll try and update the answer. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I just tested it here and it didn't fail. The ->only() method returns an array anyway.

Comment: I tested with "php": "^7.3" and "laravel/framework": "^6.0". Didn´t work for me, have to use all()

Comment: If you have a collection, you need to map it and then use the ->only() method like this: `\App\User::all()->map->only('name')->all()`. But If you have only one instance of model you just need the ->only() method like this: `\App\User::first()->only('name')`.

Comment: This is a different question, and tells us how to remove fields from the search *index*. How do we remove feilds from the *search* without removing them from the *index*? The OP may still want to search on other fields in other contexts, or use a `where()` filter on a field, such as a status field.

Comment: @RenanCoelho, may I ask you to take a look at a Laravel search related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a callback function to the scout builder instance,

```php
Person::search($searchString)->query(function($query) { 
       $query->addSelect(['title']);  
})->get();
```

Worked on `laravel 7`

Answer (score 1):

for meilisearch this worked

```
Element::search('test',
    function ($searchEngine, string $query, array $options) use ($filter) {
        $searchEngine->resetSearchableAttributes();
        $searchEngine->updateSearchableAttributes(['field_name']);
        return $searchEngine->search($query, $options);
    }
)
```

Comment: $searchEngine->updateSearchableAttributes(['*']); might not work instantly

Comment: use 
                                        app(\Laravel\Scout\EngineManager::class)->forgetDrivers();

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a callback function to the scout builder instance,

```
Person::search($searchString)->query(function($query) { 
       $query->select(['title']);  
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want standard query result, but search only in a specific column (field), you can try this solution:

```
        Element::search($query)->rule(function($builder) {
            return [
                'must' => [
                    'match' => [
                        'some_column_name' => $builder->query
                    ]
                ]
            ];
        });
```

Tested on Laravel 6, but I think it will work on later versions to...